# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Custom Workflow Action

Tags: development, workflow

I have been playing around with some custom workflow actions for SPD 2010, but I have an issue with one which works when running with the site collection admin user and not with a regular user with contribute.

The purpose of the action is to clear all permissions on an item and then in a later step add new groups/users with permissions.

But it fails, with the error code System.UnauthorizedAccessException:> Access is denied.

I use [this method](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/) to elevate.

And here is most of the code:

```
try 
{
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(__Context.Web.Site.ID, GetSystemToken(__Context.Web.Site)))
    {
        var list = __Context.Web.Lists[new Guid(__ListId)];
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("List");
        var item = list.GetItemById(__ListItem);

        item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

        // Remove current roles
        SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = item.RoleAssignmnents;

        for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                   SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
               }
               using (DisabledItemEventsScope scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
               {
                   item.Update(); 
               }
    }           
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//log
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `GetSystemToken` is correct, the following line should get you an `SPSite` object with elevated permissions.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(__Context.Web.Site.ID, GetSystemToken(__Context.Web.Site)))
```

However, you *never use this object later in your code*.

The following line is:

```
var list = __Context.Web.Lists[new Guid(__ListId)];
```

Here, you use the same context you've had from the start, so all further action happen with the same permissions. Instead, you should open an `SPWeb` from your elevated `SPSite`, and open the list thought it:

```
// open an elevated SPWeb
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    var list = web.Lists[new Guid(__ListId)];
    // ... 
}
```

Note that you've done exactly that on your solution `:)`

Personally, I like to use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, but the same issue exist in both options - you cannot use objects from the current context, they retain their original user token and permissions.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, but I guess its probably not the best way to do it. I switched to run with elevated, I'm guessing it had to do with the context and from where I did access the objects (I'm not working as a developer, just a hobby when I have time :) )

Anyway, here is my solution that is working for me now:

```
string url = __Context.Web.Url;
string listName = __Context.Web.Lists[new Guid(__ListId)].Title;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
  {
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      var list = web.Lists[listName];
      if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("List");
      var item = list.GetItemById(__ListItem);

      item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

      SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = item.RoleAssignments;
      for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
      }
      using (DisabledItemEventsScope scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
      {
        item.SystemUpdate();
      }

  }
 }
});
```